# How to map pages using the page fault handler?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, virtual-memory

I want to use the pagefault handler of my `struct vm_area_struct *` to map a physical page to user space.

Here is how I proceed:

- I globally allocate a page using `alloc_page(GFP_USER)` during the module initialization (I tried various GFP).
- I create a `struct vm_area_struct`, set a custom pagefault handler, and attach the `vma` to `current->mm`.

When a page fault occurs:

- I set `vmf->page` to the page I previously allocated and return 0.

The result is that every virtual page in the `vma` should be mapped to the same physical page after a page fault.

But here is what I noticed:

- When I write to the page from my kernel module, it's reflected in my user-space program.
- When I write to the page from my user-space, I don't see it from my kernel module.
- When I'm using `get_user_pages` in my kernel module to get the page (instead of using my global variable), I get a different physical address than the global page variable. I print the address using `page_to_phys(page)`. Writing to this page is reflected in my user-space program.

All of this is done in the page fault handler by the way.

How can this curious behavior be explained?

To access the page from kernel space, I'm using `kmap_atomic` and `kunmap_atomic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the copy-on-write mechanism.
After your page fault handler runs, the page you returned in `vmf->page` is copied to a newly allocated page. This is why your changes in user-space are not reflected in your kernel module. 
The page you were trying to read from in the kernel is not the one that was really mapped in your user-space process.

You can refer to the `do_cow_fault` function in `mm/memory.c`.