# Linux: How to mmap a sequence of physically contiguous areas into user space?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, dma, memory-mapping

In my driver I have certain number of physically contiguous DMA buffers (e.g. 4MB long each) to receive data from a device. They are handled by hardware using the SG list. As the received data will be subjected to intensive processing, I don't want to switch off cache and I will use *[dma_sync_single_for_cpu](https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux+*/+code=dma_sync_single_for_cpu)* after each buffer is filled by DMA.

To simplify data processing, I want those buffers to appear as a single huge, contiguous, circular buffer in the user space.
In case of a single buffer I simply use *[remap_pfn_range](https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux+*/+code=remap_pfn_range)* or *[dma_mmap_coherent](https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux+*/+code=dma_mmap_coherent)*. However, I can't use those functions multiple times to map consecutive buffers.

Of course, I can implement the *fault* operation in the *vm_operations* so that it finds the *pfn* of the corresponding page in the right buffer, and inserts it into the vma with [vm_insert_pfn](https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux+*/+code=vm_insert_pfn).

*The acquisition will be really fast, so I can't handle mapping when the real data arrive. But this can be solved easily. To have all mapping ready before the data acquisition starts, I can simply read the whole mmapped buffer in my application before starting the acquisition, so that all pages are already inserted when the first data arrive.*

Tha *fault* based trick should work, but maybe there is something more elegant? Just a single function, that may be called multiple times to build the whole mapping incrementally?

Additional difficulty is that the solution should be applicable (with minimal adjustments) to kernels starting from 2.6.32 to the newest one.

PS. I have seen that [annoying post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318607/how-to-map-pages-using-the-page-fault-handler). Is there a danger that if the application attempts to write something to the mmapped buffer (just doing the *in place* processing of data), my carefully built mapping will be destroyed by COW?

Comment: I've never used `vm_insert_pfn`. I generally find the logical (kernel virtual) address in the right buffer, pass that to `virt_to_page` to get a `struct page *`, then call `get_page` on the page and set `vmf->page` to the page. This works when the buffer memory is allocated by `__get_free_pages`, but probably isn't valid when the buffer memory is allocated by the `dma_alloc_...` functions. In that case, you might be able to call `dma_mmap_attrs` in a loop from the _mmap_ handler itself, adjusting `vma->vm_start`, `vma->vm_end` and `vma->vm_pgoff` before each call and restoring them at the end.

Comment: As long as your _mmap_ handler only allows shared mappings `vma->vm_flags & VM_SHARED`, I don't think you need to worry about COW.

Comment: Unfortunately, *dma_mmap_attrs* first appeared in 3.5 . I can't use it in the 2.6.32 compatible driver.
I can see two drivers in 2.6.32 kernal that use *vm_insert_pfn* - i915_gem.c and b3dfg.c. In both cases *get_page* is not called before inserting.

Comment: In case of b3dfg.c the memory containing the inserted pages was allocated with kmalloc.
Allocation: 
 https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux+v2.6.32/drivers/staging/b3dfg/b3dfg.c#L894

Inserting: 
https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux+v2.6.32/drivers/staging/b3dfg/b3dfg.c#L452

Comment: An example of the use of `get_page` in a fault handler is in "drivers/uio/uio.c" when the memory type being mmap'ed is `UIO_MEM_LOGICAL`. Although none of the client drivers in "drivers/uio/" actually use that memory type, that is the one that would be used for kernel memory allocated by `kmalloc`, `alloc_pages`, etc. There are a few other places in the kernel that use `get_page` in the fault handler, such as "drivers/scsi/sg.c", but those are harder to follow.

Comment: I have found one interesting detail. In the b3dfg.c driver, the vma is marked with the following flags: VM_IO | VM_RESERVED | VM_CAN_NONLINEAR |  VM_PFNMAP; even though it was allocated with kmalloc (?!)
https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux+v2.6.32/drivers/staging/b3dfg/b3dfg.c#L841 
That's probably, why it does not need get_page and is inserted with vm_insert_pfn.
I'll test this approach in my code.

Comment: It is interesting, if avoiding of usage of the "page struct" and using raw PFNs is a generally good approach... The VM_PFNMAP wasn't widely used in 2.6.32 (just in the b3dfg.c and in drm_gem.c drivers), but seems to be often used in 4.9. Does the official kernel documentation suggests when to use a standard mapping, and when it is better to use raw PFNs?

Answer (score 1):

Below is my solution that works for buffers allocated with `dmam_alloc_noncoherent`.

Allocation of the buffers:

```
[...]
for(i=0;i<DMA_NOFBUFS;i++) {
    ext->buf_addr[i] = dmam_alloc_noncoherent(&my_dev->dev, DMA_BUFLEN, &my_dev->buf_dma_t[i],GFP_USER);
    if(my_dev->buf_addr[i] == NULL) {
        res = -ENOMEM;
        goto err1;
    }
    //Make buffer ready for filling by the device
    dma_sync_single_range_for_device(&my_dev->dev, my_dev->buf_dma_t[i],0,DMA_BUFLEN,DMA_FROM_DEVICE);
}
[...]
```

Mapping of the buffers

```
void swz_mmap_open(struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
}

void swz_mmap_close(struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
}

static int swz_mmap_fault(struct vm_area_struct *vma, struct vm_fault *vmf)
{
    long offset;
    char * buffer = NULL;
    int buf_num = 0;
    //Calculate the offset (according to info in https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux+v2.6.32/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915_gem.c#L1195 it is better not ot use the vmf->pgoff )
    offset = (unsigned long)(vmf->virtual_address - vma->vm_start);
    buf_num = offset/DMA_BUFLEN;
    if(buf_num > DMA_NOFBUFS) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Access outside the buffer\n");
        return -EFAULT;
    }
    offset = offset - buf_num * DMA_BUFLEN;
    buffer = my_dev->buf_addr[buf_num];
    vm_insert_pfn(vma,(unsigned long)(vmf->virtual_address),virt_to_phys(&buffer[offset]) >> PAGE_SHIFT);         
    return VM_FAULT_NOPAGE;
}

struct vm_operations_struct swz_mmap_vm_ops =
{
    .open =     swz_mmap_open,
    .close =    swz_mmap_close,
    .fault =    swz_mmap_fault,    
};

static int char_sgdma_wz_mmap(struct file *file, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
    vma->vm_ops = &swz_mmap_vm_ops;
    vma->vm_flags |= VM_IO | VM_RESERVED | VM_CAN_NONLINEAR | VM_PFNMAP;
    swz_mmap_open(vma);
    return 0;
}
```